# Magento Rest Api Invalid XML

Tags: xml, rest, magento, magento-1.9

Hi I am trying to access Magento Rest Api through http://magentostore/api/rest. But I am getting response

`<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
        <faultcode>Sender</faultcode>
          <faultstring>Invalid XML</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`.

Does anybody have any idea regarding this. Why I am recieving this error

Comment: Could you provide more details on what it is exactly you're trying to do? What URL are you trying to approach? What's the data you are sending? etc.

Comment: I am trying to access this url. http://working.headline-shop.com/api/rest/ but it is returning me invalid xml error

Comment: I am trying to access the url in browser

Answer (score 1):

You will need to adjust your .htaccess file.

Uncomment Line 12 `Options -Multiview`

This turns off Multiview and your rest api should work.

Comment: Why does the API fail with "Invalid XML" when that line is not there?